# How to parse single file for different outputs

Tags: logstash

Does somebody know how to parse single line from a file and parse it for different outputs? For example: input is a log file, outputs are elasticsearch indices with different templates. I need to parse every line and save it into the first index and some of lines which has a promo code (like `?promo=wteaewfsthser`) I need to put to another index as well. I think it's possible to use two logstash instances (correct me if I'm wrong please). But I want to know is it possible to use single instance of logstash and one configuration file?

Thanks,
Igor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [clone](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-clone.html).  Note that only the filters that are present after the clone{} will be run on the cloned event.